# XML schema for ordered child elements with different names

Tags: c#, xml, schema, xsd

I need to Deserialize an XML that contains the definition of a Profile/polygon of points and arcs.

```
<Pt>
    <X>0.0</X>
    <Y>0.0</Y>
</Pt>
<Arc>
    <X>0.0</X>
    <Y>0.0</Y>
    <Rad>0.0</Rad>
</Arc>
```

Actual XML file:

```
<Profile>
    <Pt>...</Pt>
    <Pt>...</Pt>
    <Arc>...</Arc>
    <Pt>...</Pt>
    <Arc>...</Arc>
</Profile>
```

I am a little stuck finding a solution to know the order of child elements with different names.  I am currently using something a schema that looks like the below code, but I obviously get individual arrays of Pts and Arcs without knowing the order of the Pts and Arcs.  I have tried creating a substitutionGroup (Point) that takes both Pt and Arc, but I was not successful.

```
<xs:element name="Profile">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Pt">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="X" type="xs:decimal" />
            <xs:element name="Z" type="xs:decimal" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Arc">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="X" type="xs:decimal" />
            <xs:element name="Z" type="xs:decimal" />
            <xs:element name="Rad" type="xs:decimal" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. I doubt I've ever heard of such thing as the order of deserialization elements, because that's irrelevant for created class object. Are you sure it's really deserialization you're after?

Comment: I am using (MySchemaClass)XMLSerializer.Deserialize() on a xml file, where MySchemaClass was compiled with xsd MyScheme.xsd /classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to permit an arbitrary order of your `Pt` and `Arc` elements. The following schema will do the trick by setting `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in the `sequence` declaration. You will also have to correct your `Pt` and `Arc` declarations since currently they are using `Z` and not `Y` as in your data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="pt-type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="X" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element name="Y" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="arc-type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="X" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element name="Y" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element name="Rad" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Profile">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:choice >
          <xs:element name="Pt" type="pt-type"/>
          <xs:element name="Arc" type="arc-type"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This works great!  I think I understand out the type works now.  I set both Pt and Arc under profile to arc-type.  If radius is zero then it is a Pt.  Then whenever I deserialize I get one array of arc-type[] with the points/arc in the order defined in the XML file.  Thanks!